# Nuxt js this.$route.query is always empty

Tags: nuxt.js

Accessing the route.query object but it's always empty
`this.$route` results in

```
fullPath: "/login/asset"
hash: ""
meta: {}
name: "login-app"
params: {app: "asset"}
path: "/login/asset"
query: {}
```

I tried setting the router.push in the following ways `this.$router.push('login/asset?ID=44')` and also `this.$router.push({ path: 'login/asset', query: { ID: 44 } })`

Need the route query to be processed on another page

Comment: should work. create repro on codesadnbox

Comment: this.$route.params.id should do the trick

Comment: @Loki `this.$route.params.id` is to get the Route Parameters. Still I checked the `this.$route.params` and got `{app: asset}`. I need to access query i.e. `?ID=44`